# Ruby SFTP returns "Net::SSH::Disconnect: disconnected: Failed to read binary packet data! (2)"

Tags: ruby, ssh, ftp, sftp, net-sftp

I have this in ruby 1.9.3:

```
Net::SFTP.start(ENV['SFTP_HOST'], ENV['SFTP_USERNAME'], password: ENV['SFTP_PASSWORD'], key_data: [ENV['SFTP_KEY']], keys_only: true) do |sftp|
  sftp.upload!(StringIO.new("testing"), "/text.txt")
end
```

It appears to do the authentication step correctly (I can list files in a directory etc) but when I do the `upload!` command like above it returns:

```
Net::SSH::Disconnect: disconnected: Failed to read binary packet data! (2)
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:176:in `block in poll_message'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:166:in `loop'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:166:in `poll_message'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:451:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:213:in `preprocess'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:197:in `process'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `block in loop'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:802:in `loop'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/operations/upload.rb:195:in `wait'
from /Users/barmstrong/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-sftp-2.0.5/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:103:in `upload!'
```

I also tried

```
    # open and write to a pseudo-IO for a remote file
    sftp.file.open("/test.txt", "wb") do |f|
      f.puts "testing"
    end
```

To try writing a binary file, but no luck.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Anything in the logs on the SFTP server? Does it work locally?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to access the logs on the server.  But uploading works when I connect with Transmit (an FTP client on mac) using the same credentials.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2):

Well I found a solution but I have no idea why it works.

Just playing around I added `sftp.dir.foreach("/") {|e| puts e.name }` right before the `upload!` and it worked!

So it looks like this now.

```
Net::SFTP.start(ENV['SFTP_HOST'], ENV['SFTP_USERNAME'], password: ENV['SFTP_PASSWORD'], key_data: [ENV['SFTP_KEY']], keys_only: true) do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.foreach("/") {}
  sftp.upload!(StringIO.new("testing"), "/text.txt")
end
```

Doing a `dir` shouldn't have any effect, but for some reason it does.  If anyone has some insight on this I'd be curious.  Thanks!

Btw, the ftp server identifies itself as "SSH-2.0-Maverick_SSHD" for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I was having exact same problem and couldn't figure out a solution! This worked. I also can't figure out why. My best guess, is that it has to do with how remote server handles sessions. In my case exact same code works with 4 out of 5 servers ( servers are on the vendor's side, and each vendor has their own flavor).